# Loaded content jQuery action inactive

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why a jquery action of a loaded page "edit_img.php" doesn't work whereas this jquery action works when "edit_img.php" is opened like a normal php page (not a loaded content with load() )

The way "edit_img.php" is loaded :

```
    $("button#edit_img").click(function(){
        $('div#profil_wall').load("edit_img.php"); 
    });
```

"edit_img.php" jquery action which doesn't work :

```
    $("button#show_info").click(function(){
        $('div#mini_div_info').show();  
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide more context around this problem.  The information in your post likely won't be enough for the community to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm quite the pedantic bore tonight. ;-) --> since you are targeting ID's (already unique on your page), you don't need to include the element type in your selector. Just the ID by itself will perform better (though admittedly, probably only a profiler could tell; humans likely won't notice a difference)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because it is added after the DOM has been loaded. Add to the page that calls the `load` function on `click`:

```
$(document).on("click", "button#show_info", function(){ 
    $('div#mini_div_info').show();  
 });
```

And you can remove the `click` function code from `edit_img.php`

Here is a demo of the jquery `.on` function: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/76KJ8/

Or, as Greg suggests:

```
$("div#profil_wall").on("click", "button#show_info", function(){ 
    $('div#mini_div_info').show();  
 });
```

Comment: No need to make `document` the listener when you know that the dynamic content is being loaded into `#profil_wall`

Comment: @GregPettit That came straight from the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/live/ scroll down to `rewriting the .live() method`.

Comment: Sure, but there's no reason to use the `live()` method here. What you want is to rewrite the `delegate()` method! In other words, before `.on()` came around, you may have recommended `live()` and I would have commented that `delegate()` is a better choice since we know of a non-destroyed ancestor.

Comment: Hello, I have been trying your solutions since yesterday, doesn't work. What a terrible problem to add a loaded content to the DOM. I'm lost. Can you implement my example with live() or delegate() to show me a third example ?

Comment: @Anon I would be completely guessing from what little info you gave in your question. Very hard to do example with your code as shown. Load the content, not the jquery, into your `div#profil_wall`. Use jquery's `.on` method to add your `click` handlers to the page calling the `load`.